# Highway and Freeway Signs in Google Maps Styling

Tags: javascript, google-maps, styles

I am new to Javascript and have been trying to style a Google Maps overlay to make it look better in a design of mine.

I seem to have everything working right however I can't figure out how to get the Highway and Freeway signs to not change color when I change the color of the roads `"featureType": "road.highway",`

As seen here the orange ovals and square are street signs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFR8Z.png

Here is a link to my JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kaynolliee/UNs7B/1/

Any help would be great I just can't seem to figure this one out.